# Why is host.run() just opening localhost

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

In the kestrel part of my BuildWebHost, I can verify that the url is set to https://localhost/5000. However, when host.run() is called, only `https://localhost` is launched for some reason.

`

```
.UseKestrel(options =>
                {
                    X509Certificate2 certificate = null;
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(certFileName) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(certPassword))
                    {
                        certificate = new X509Certificate2(certFileName, certPassword);
                        url = "https://localhost:5000";
                    }

                    options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 5000, listenOptions =>
                    {
                        if (certificate != null)
                        {
                            listenOptions.UseHttps(certificate);
                        }
                    });
                })
```

`

Additional Information:
It's launched when I run Visual Studio Code. My configurations files all say localhost:5000 This used to work. I changed my program property in launch.json to point at net2.0 path and that's when it stopped.

launch.json contents:
`

```
{
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (web)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            // If you have changed target frameworks, make sure to update the program path.
            // "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.1/TennisFolderAPI.dll",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0/TennisFolderAPI.dll",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",
            "launchBrowser": {
                "enabled": true,
                "args": "${auto-detect-url}",
                "windows": {
                    "command": "cmd.exe",
                    "args": "/C start ${auto-detect-url}"
                },
                "osx": {
                    "command": "open"
                },
                "linux": {
                    "command": "xdg-open"
                }
            },
            "env": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
            },
            "sourceFileMap": {
                "/Views": "${workspaceFolder}/Views"
            },
            "requireExactSource": false,
        },
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Attach",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "attach",
            "processId": "${command:pickProcess}"
        }
```

`

Comment: Launched from where?  Visual studio?  If so check your project properties.

Comment: It's launched when I run Visual Studio. My configurations files all say `localhost:5000` This used to work. I changed my `program` property in launch.json to point at net2.0 path and that's when it stopped.

Comment: That would be good information to include in your question, along with the contents of that file.

Answer (score 1):

For Visual Studio in launchSettings.json use "launchUrl": "http://localhost:5000".

Launch.json is for Visual Studio Code.

https://www.google.com/amp/s/andrewlock.net/how-to-set-the-hosting-environment-in-asp-net-core/amp/

Comment: Thanks, but it looks like the launch.json equivalent doesn't have that option.

Comment: You said you were using Visual Studio?

Comment: I fixed it, but it looks like it might be due to a db migration. I undid my migration and it looks like the browser tries to open with the right port. But once i migrate my db it stops.